Execution failed for task ':connectivity_plus:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. I didnot find solution yet
I am trying to build flutter apk on debug mode from android studio.
Flutter run I get this error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':connectivity_plus:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


Could not resolve all files for configuration ':connectivity_plus:androidJdkImage'.
Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: C:\Users\netway\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-34\core-for-system-modules.jar.
> Error while executing process C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\jbr\bin\jlink.exe with arguments {--module-path C:\Users\netway.gradle\caches\transforms-3\28ce91939b758cd91c8f8fd1564bffac\transformed\output\temp\jmod --add-modules java.base --output C:\Users\netway.gradle\caches\transforms-3\28ce91939b758cd91c8f8fd1564bffac\transformed\output\jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}

I m using below dependency.
pubspec.yaml
connectivity_plus: ^6.1.0

Check if you full-fill all requirements for android version given in https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus.
